# Best performance of getting values of the dictionary in python

Tags: python

```
Table = u'''A,This is A
B,This is B
C,This is C
D,This is D
E,This is E
F,This is F
G,This is G
H,This is H
I,This is I
J,This is J'''

SearchValue = u'''A
B
C
D
Bang
F
Bang
G
H'''

Table = Table.splitlines()
LineText = {}
for targetLineText in Table:
    LineText[targetLineText.split(',')[0]] = targetLineText.split(',')[1]

SearchValue = SearchValue.splitlines()
for targetValue in SearchValue:
    print LineText[targetValue] if targetValue in LineText else 'Error:' + targetValue
```

What this code is doing is...
It finds value lists from the 'Table' dictionary by keys called 'SearchValue'

I check if the key exists by the following code..

```
targetValue in LineText
```

What I want to do to get the value at the same time of the key value existing check. Because I think that performs better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should take a look to the [dict.get](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method :

```
SearchValue = SearchValue.splitlines()
for targetValue in SearchValue:
    print LineText.get(targetValue, 'Error:' + targetValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've reformatted your code according to [the python style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and added some optimizations:

```
table = u'''A,This is A
B,This is B
C,This is C
D,This is D
E,This is E
F,This is F
G,This is G
H,This is H
I,This is I
J,This is J'''

search_value = u'''A
B
C
D
Bang
F
Bang
G
H'''

line_text = dict(line.split(",") for line in table.splitlines())

for target_value in search_value.splitlines():
    print line_text.get(target_value, "Error: {0}".format(target_value))
```

Comment: SO NICE!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!! I gotta know about the python style